# When is the flow of a (semi)dynamical system nonsingular?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lebesgue-measure, transformation

Consider an autonomous system described by
\begin{equation}
\dot{x}=F(x),
\end{equation}
where $F\in C^1(X)$. Define the semigroup of transformations $\{\mathcal{S}_t\}_{t\geq0}$ as
$$\mathcal{S}_t(x_0)=x(t),$$
where $x(t)$ is the solution of the ODE above, corresponding to the initial condition $x(0)=x_0\in X$.

*Definition.* Given a measure space $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$, we say that a semigroup of transformations $\{\mathcal{S}_t\}_{t\geq0}$ is nonsingular if for all $t\geq0$
$$\mu(\mathcal{S}^{-1}_t(A))=0 \qquad \text{for each $A\in\mathcal{A}$ such that $\mu(A)=0$}.$$

(A semigroup of transformations is nonsingular as long as it does not map sets of measure non-zero to sets of measure zero.)

*Conjecture.* Let $X=\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure, and $\mathcal{A}$ be the usual $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $\{\mathcal{S}_t\}_{t\geq0}$ is nonsingular if $F\in C^1(X)$.

How can I prove/disprove the above?

Comment: I guess that the starting point is that the flow of a $C^1$ system is continuous.

Comment: The obvious non-$C^1$ demonstration example is $\dot x=-2\sqrt{|x|}$, where all solutions after some time end up in the zero point.